# how to copy elements from a map to a std:: string

Tags: c++, string, vector, stdmap

I am writing a program that implements a uni-directional graph using `std::map`. I have to search for the key and then copy the vector values corresponding to that key into a new location in the map. The problem is that the key I search for is extracted from yet another location in the map. I understand why I am getting the error as `std::copy_n` does not copy from vector to string (although it works the other way) but I don't know how to fix this.
 I am copying a snippet of the code below:
 The keys to search for are stored in a vector corresponding to key mykey.

```
for (
    vector<string>::iterator itr = mymap.find(mykey)->second.begin()
  ; itr != mymap.find(mykey)->second.end()
  ; itr++
  )
{
    string find_key = "";

    // error C2664 :cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>' 
    // to 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &'
    std::copy_n(itr, 1, find_key.begin()); 

    if (mymap.find(find_key) == mymap.end())
        cout << "key not found" << endl;
    else 
        mymap[mykey].insert(
            mymap.find(find_key)->second.begin()
          , mymap.find(find_key)->second.end()
          );
}
```

Edit:  using stringstream to extract key from map

for (vector::iterator itr =mymap.find(mykey)->second.begin(); itr!=mymap.find(mykey)->second.end();++itr){

```
    stringstream ss;
    ss<< *itr;
    string find_key = ss.str();
        if (mymap.find(find_key)==mymap.end())
    cout<<"key not found"<<endl;
    else 
        for (vector<string>::iterator mapit= mymap.find(find_key)->second.begin(); mapit!=mymap.find(find_key)->second.end(); ++mapit)
    mymap[mykey].push_back(*mapit);}

}
```

I am now getting a "vector not incrementable" error. Can you please tell me why?Also, what happens to duplicate values in a map? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: why don't you edit **your** code instead of keeping this mistake??

Answer (score 0):

`copy_n` with a size one copy only one element (of course), but you're mixing an input iterator on `string` and an output iterator on `char`.

So do you want to read the first character of the current string or the whole string? I guess the second makes more sense in your context. So you could simple deference the iterator:

```
string const& find_key = *itr;
```

Regarding performance, even though I do not recommend to look into optimizations too earlier in the development of your software, here you perform some searches way too many times.

For example, in the first loop, at every iteration you'll look for `mykey` in your map. You could rewrite it using C++11 features:

```
for (auto const& str : mymap.find(mykey)->second)
```

This will call `find` once only and iterate on the (assuming to be existing) associated `vector` of `string`.

Here I guess that `str` is what you called `find_key` in your original post.

Then again you call three times `mymap.find(find_key)`. That can be optimized quite easily. Additionally, does the `insert` compile? I couldn't find a matching function in the doc...

```
auto it = mymap.find(find_key);
if (it == mymap.end()) {
    cout << "key not found" << endl;
} else {
    auto const& vec = *it; // a ref to vector of strings to be copied
    auto& dest = mymap[mykey];
    dest.insert(std::end(dest), std::begin(vec), std::end(vec));
}
```

And when we put everything together we get:

```
for (auto const& find_key : mymap.find(mykey)->second) {
    auto it = mymap.find(find_key);
    if (it == mymap.end()) {
        std::cout << "key not found" << std::endl;
    } else {
        auto const& vec = *it; // a ref to vector of strings to be copied
        auto& dest = mymap[mykey];
        dest.insert(std::end(dest), std::begin(vec), std::end(vec));
    }
}
```

Doesn't that make more sense? ;-)